# generate link to pages in laravel issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem with link in laravel.

I have this route:

```
$lingua = Request::segment(1);

Route::group(array('prefix' => $lingua), function()
{

    Route::get('/', 'ItemController@menu');
    Route::get('/{idcampo}/{idcat}','ItemController@show');
});
```

The first is language and request the 1st segment, and use as prefix. in /
THis is my ItemController Controller

```
public function menu()

    {$lingua = Request::segment(1);
        return View::make('index', ['categorie'=>DB::table('cat_nome')->join('lingua', 'cat_nome.id_lingua', '=', 'lingua.id') ->where('lingua.lingua','=',$lingua)->get(),
                                    'campi' => DB::table('campo_nome')->join('lingua', 'campo_nome.id_lingua', '=', 'lingua.id') ->where('lingua.lingua','=',$lingua)->get(),
                                    'lingua'=>$lingua,
                                    ]
            );
    }


    public function show($camps,$cats)
    {$lingua = Request::segment(1);

    return View::make('categorie', ['categorie'=>DB::table('cat_nome')->join('lingua', 'cat_nome.id_lingua', '=', 'lingua.id') ->where('lingua.lingua','=',$lingua)->get(),
                                    'campi' => DB::table('campo_nome')->join('lingua', 'campo_nome.id_lingua', '=', 'lingua.id') ->where('lingua.lingua','=',$lingua)->get(),
                                    'dd' => DB::table('description')->join('lingua', 'description.id_lingua', '=', 'lingua.id')->where('lingua.lingua','=',$lingua)->where ('description.id_cat','=',$cats)->where ('description.id_campo','=',$camps)->select('description.descrizione')->get(),
                                    'lingua' => $lingua,
                                    ]);
    }
```

In index i query a the entries of a menu.

```
@foreach ($campi as $campo)
{{$campo->nome}}
<ul class="list-unstyled">
@foreach($categorie as $categoria)
<li> <a href="{{$lingua}}/{{$campo->id_campo}}/{{$categoria->id_cat}}">{{$categoria->nome}}</a> </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@endforeach
```

Now when i pass to the controller, i keep the menu visualized and i visualize the single entries of the database (the description).

My problem is that when i click the first time on the link, which appear to be:
language/id1/id2
I go in the right page, visualize the description of the product BUT now the link on the side menu became:

language/id1/language/id1/id2

But it should always be language/id1/id2 even when i am in Itemcontroller@show

The second time the link are generated in the side menu, something is added on the link, and i can't quite understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to use URL::to like this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to($lingua. '/'. $campo->id_campo. '/'. $categoria->id_cat) }}">
```

Comment: It creates an absolute URL to your link, preventing your problem with relative linking that kept adding language/id1 to the current url.